# Como fazer um datalist com as opções geradas com um json usando angularjs?

Tags: html5, angularjs, json

Eu queria que ao preencher o campo de profissões, aparecesse uma lista com as profissões já cadastradas para o usuário final, como forma de ajudar o usuário seguir um padrão para os nomes. Então pensei um usar um datalist que mostrasse as profissões já cadastradas. Eu criei um json que lista as profissões já cadastradas na tabela, bem como também um controlador usando angularjs que puxa esses dados.
Pesquisando, encontrei duas formas de fazer o meu datalist, uma usando a tag option, outra usando a tag select, o problema é que nenhuma funciona da maneira que eu queria.

Quando uso o option, ele renderiza da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando uso o select, ele renderiza assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo estão os meus códigos:

Controlador:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('profissoesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.profissoes = [];
var carregarProfissoes = function (){
    $http.get("ListaProfissoes.php").then(function(response){
        $scope.profissoes=response.data;
    });
};
carregarProfissoes();
```

Meu html, usando o option:

```html
<datalist ng-controller="profissoesCtrl" id="profissoes"> 
   <option ng-repeat="p in profissoes" value="{{p}}">
 </datalist>
```

Meu html usando o select:

```html
<datalist ng-controller="profissoesCtrl" id="profissoes"> 
 <select class="oculto" ng-model="aluno.profissao" ng-options="p.profissao as p.profissao for p in profissoes" > </select>
 </datalist>
```

Desde já, agradeço a todos que responderem!

Comment: tente usar ``response.data.profissao`` com option, assim: ``$scope.profissoes=response.data.profissao;``

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso, mas não funcionou, ele retorna undefined ao dar um console.log em $scope.profissoes tentando dessa forma.

Comment: Caiu a minha ficha, foi erro bobo, na tag options eu deveria ter colado o value com p.profissao, ai deu certo, de qualquer modo, muito obrigado